# Cannot load "forecast" package for R

Tags: r, loading, forecast

I downloaded the forecast package by using

```
install.packages("forecast")
library("forecast)
```

But when I try to load the package, I receive the following:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in
>   dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): unable to load shared object
>   '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4.1-MRO/Resources/library/fracdiff/libs/fracdiff.so':
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4.1
>   MRO/Resources/library/fracdiff/libs/fracdiff.so, 6): Library not
>   loaded:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
>
> ```
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4.1-MRO/Resources/library/fracdiff/libs/fracdiff.so
>
> Reason: image not found
> ```

My session info is below:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8
```

Comment: There's an issue with the BLAS—either files got moved or a path is set incorrectly. Unless you have reason not to, a simple solution is to just update to R 3.5, which will supersede the problematic installation.

Comment: Are you using R from CRAN, MS R Open or some other R distribution?

Comment: Also, I just heard that forecast is being superseded by [fable](https://github.com/tidyverts/fable)